# access user calendar with service account

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a php application on my intranet that needs to add events in the calenders of my users.

I followed the following instructing
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation

I setup the google-api-php client  and used the example service-accounts.php as my starting point.

```
$client_id = 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'file.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("egw - intranet");
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
//authenticate
if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary('API V3 TEST');
$event->setLocation('rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr');
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2014-11-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2014-11-04T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('email@domain.com');

$attendees = array($attendee1);
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$createdEvent = $service->events- >insert('email2@domain.com', $event);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

I'm recieving 404 not found error. 
If I manually share the calendar I am using for my test with the service account, It works. But I would like for my program to also work without manually sharing each and every calendar of all my users.  Can somebody tell me what I am missing?

Kind regards,

Comment: Have you set up the scopes correctly in the admin console? You should have this one in there: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Comment: Yes, I have https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar as scope.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an event to a calendar that has not been specifically shared with your Google project.  You must either share each calendar with the service account, or you must use OAuth2 with web application credentials so that each user can give you access.

Comment: Is that not exactly why 'service accounts' exist within the app domain?

Comment: The service account simply allows your app to identify itself to Google. The owner of the account still has to give the app permission to access their calendar. From a calendar you want to modify, go to Settings -> Calendars -> Share this calendar. Enter the email address (service account name) from your service account and give it "make changes to events" permissions. Be sure and click the Save button at the bottom of the page. If your code is correct, and at a glance it appears to be, it will add events.

Comment: If the domain admin has allowed domain level access to calendars shouldn't that also "automatically" give the service account access as well?  The API docs on this information is far from complete and hardly useful.

Comment: Theoretically, you can update the entire domains user list using these instructions: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en

Use the directory API instead of the Provisioning API to get the user list.

Answer (score 0):

When I started this the current client google-php-api-client was 1.1.0-beta. Some weeks later we are now at 1.1.2. Upgrading to this version resolved my problem. 
Adding a service-account gives an application the possibility to identify itself with Google.
If you add the scopes to the google admin console as I have done, The service-account has access to all the data specified by the scope for every user in the domain.
Thx all for the responses.