# Why does this attempt to pull a list of events always return a 404 error?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

As far as I can tell, the following *should* work.  It's pulled from example code, and similar requests [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802786/access-user-calendar-with-service-account) are resolved fine.  Yes, scopes are set up; and yes, the calendar in question is specifically shared.  Here's the code -- you'll note that I'm just trying to get things to work at this point, but the error data isn't terribly helpful:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

require_once 'google_settings.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

$client_id = GA_CLIENT_ID; //Client ID
$service_account_name = GA_SERVICE_EMAIL; //Email Address
$key_file_location = GA_KEY_FILE_LOCATION; //key.p12
if ($client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>' || !strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
    echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
}
try {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Just Testing");
    $client->setDeveloperKey(GA_API_KEY);
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $optParams = array();
    $results = $service->events->listEvents('xyzxyz', $optParams);
    echo "<h3>Results Of Call:</h3>\n<pre>";
    if (is_array($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $item) {
            var_dump($item);
            echo "\n\n";
        }
    } else var_dump($results);
    echo "\n</pre>";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The error I always get looks like this (regardless of which test calendar I use -- yes I've enabled sharing individually):

`Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xyzxyz?key=<key_appears_here>: (404) Not Found`

Should this work?  Am I just not seeing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Is "xyzxyz" is the calendar id where you want to list events from? Did you give domain wide delegation(https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) to your service account which grants access to user's data? Also, you can try your request in google API explorer https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: Yes, "xyzxyz" is the calendar id (the actual is, of course, different).  Yes, I gave domain wide delegation to my service account.  And my request works in the API explorer -- sorry for not mentioning that I tried that too -- it even uses an identical URL to communicate with google when I look behind the scenes on my page.  I'm totally flummoxed.

Comment: After looking again at the [OAuth Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority), I thought perhaps that I needed to specify a user that I was impersonating like so: `$cred->sub = 'name@domain.com';`, but that doesn't help.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: In the PHP client library you can impersonate a user by setting the sub field on the Google_AssertionCredentials object you created.

$auth->sub = $userEmail;

Comment: @SGC I don't understand how what you just said is different than my previous comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around I found [this getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php).  I followed the [link in Step 1, part 1](https://console.developers.google.com/start/api?id=calendar); but the Calendar API had already shown as enabled in the Developer's Console, so I'm not sure this did anything.  **However**, I had never entered the **Consent screen** information as described in Step 1, part 2, and when I tested my code *at that point*, without further modification, it worked.

I had left the **Consent screen** information blank because my application only uses Public API access, but it appears that the consent screen data *has to be entered* regardless of whether you intend to use it or not.